# Unable to access link menu options using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver. I am unable to access link menu options.eg:I want to access options "Casual shoes" option under "Men" menu link from flipkart site. i tried using below code

```
WebElement a= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[title='Men']"));
a.click();
```

but unable to click on menu link "Men"

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is wrong you forget to add @ in front of attribute. You are using `//a[title='Men']` but you should use `//a[@title='Men']`

Below code is working for me:-

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Men']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Casual Shoes')]")).click();
```

OR

In chrome below code is working fine for me:-

```
WebElement we =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Men']"));   
we.click();
WebElement Causual =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Casual Shoes')]"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Causual);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 36 milliseconds